# Firefox does not accept e-mail whith blank space on end

Tags: html, email, firefox, mozilla

I would like to make my website work identically on every browser. 
Unfortunately, the validation mechanism introduced their differences.

Field of type 'e-mail' on Chrome and Opera 'trim';delete blank spaces on input of e-mail field and Firefox no cuts signs and do not accept e-mail in this form.

`<input type="email" id="e-mail" class="" name="e-mail" value="" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">`

Example:

[image]

Comment: where's your code? and this seems php-related

Comment: I explore the prospects for a user does not have the possibility of insight into the code.

Comment: sorry but I don't know what you mean, in comments and for the question. Update your question and be clearer and with code. Other than that, I can't help; maybe someone else will understand what you mean.

Comment: Change `type="email"` to `type="text"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to get the same behavior between browsers while keeping the email verification, you can trim the field on blur:

```js
document.getElementById("e-mail").addEventListener("blur",function(e){
    this.value = this.value.trim();
});
```

```html
<input type="email" id="e-mail" class="" name="e-mail" value="" placeholder="" autocomplete="off">
```